# На хостинге не работает перевод через ini файл

Tags: php, html, ini

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой проблемой. На локалке делал сайт. В конце создал перевод через ini файл. На локалке все прекрасно работало, но как только я залил сайт на хост то перевод через ini файл перестал работать. Ошибок никаких нет. В интернете ничего не нашел. Помогите пожалуйста, уже пару дней мучаюсь. Ссылка на сайт: https://skalettawebsite.000webhostapp.com

```
<?php
  $path = $_GET["language"];
  if (isset($path)) {
    $language = parse_ini_file("language/" . $path);
  }
  else {
    $path="ru.ini";
    $language = parse_ini_file("language/" . $path);
  }
 ?>


<div class="darknes__blocks">
      <h3 class="darknes__languege">Язык</h3>
        <form class="languege"  method="get" >
          <button  type="submit" name="language" value="ru.ini" class="darknes__button_language button">
            <h5 class="darknes__buttom_text_languege darknes__buttom_text_languege-ru">Русский</h5>
          </button>
          <button  type="submit" name="language" value="en.ini" class="darknes__button_language_en button">
            <h5 class="darknes__buttom_text_languege darknes__buttom_text_languege-en">English</h5>
          </button>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Обратитесь на хостинг. Возможно там отключена эта функция. А вообще, надо включить вывод ошибок в лог, и читать его. Наверняка там это как раз и написано

Comment: Тут дело не в хосте. Друг использует этот же хост и все работает